# AWS Batch input parameters from Cloudwatch Event

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I'm trying to setup an AWS Batch job that is triggered from a Cloudwatch Event on a S3 PutObject into a bucket. I have the job running when the new file is added, but am not sure how to pass the filename to the job. In my Cloudwatch Event Rule, I set the `Configure input` to `Matched event` for the batch job queue, but am not sure how to access the event in the docker container that the job is running.

Comment: I've tried printing the environment variables in the container, but am not seeing anything that looks like the event.

Comment: As a work around, I am using the same rule to trigger the job and add the event to an SQS queue for the job to read and delete.

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html, towards the bottom, in the section titled "Passing Event Information to an AWS Batch Target using the CloudWatch Events Input Transformer":

Set your job definition up like so:

```
{
  "jobDefinitionName": "echo-parameters",
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "busybox",
    "vcpus": 2,
    "memory": 2000,
    "command": [
      "echo",
      "Ref::S3bucket",
      "Ref::S3key"
    ]
  }
}
```

This assumes your docker image contains a command `echo` which takes 2 parameters - an S3 bucket and an S3 key.

In your CloudWatch Event rule, use an InputTransformer to transform the event details into what you want:

```
"InputTransformer": {
  "InputPathsMap" : {
    "S3BucketValue": "$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName",
    "S3KeyValue": "$.detail.requestParameters.key"
  },
  "InputTemplate" : "{\"S3bucket\": <S3BucketValue>, \"S3key\": <S3KeyValue>}"
}
```

Comment: According to the latest documentation, the template should be {"Parameters" : {"S3bucket": <S3BucketValue>, "S3key": <S3KeyValue>}}